# How can I change the bulma placeholder color?

Tags: css, placeholder, bulma, buefy

I need to change the color of the bulma CSS placeholder. 
I can use the code below for placeholders of normal input that is not bulma,

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

but it doesnt work on buefy input field that is powered with bulma. I want you to know I have already setup sass for bulma editing and it works fine, but I dont know the placeholder of input field class to toggle it.

Comment: Is this possible for 1 single input, potentially inline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

alright, found it:

```
$input-placeholder-color:
```

you can just change that in your sass editing file!

Comment: You'd think they'd mention that in the [Input > Variables docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/input/#variables)...

Answer (score 4):

Just want to add that it should be before the import of the bulma files:

```
$input-placeholder-color: red;
@import "bulma";
```

would work.